# Python Plotly histogram bins by day and month but not week

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am following the example found here: https://plot.ly/python/aggregations/#histogram-binning

The code they have works as expected, but I am trying to expand it to autobin by week as well as day, month, etc. I know this data set doesn't have time, but I would also like to bin my own set of data that has time using hour as well. It seems like this would be straightforward, but this code does not produce the correct results:

```
import plotly.io as pio

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://plot.ly/~public.health/17.csv")

data = [dict(
  x = df['date'],
  autobinx = False,
  autobiny = True,
  marker = dict(color = 'rgb(68, 68, 68)'),
  name = 'date',
  type = 'histogram',
  xbins = dict(
    end = '2016-12-31 12:00',
    size = 'M1',
    start = '1983-12-31 12:00'
  )
)]

layout = dict(
  paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(240, 240, 240)',
  plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(240, 240, 240)',
  title = '<b>Shooting Incidents</b>',
  xaxis = dict(
    title = '',
    type = 'date'
  ),
  yaxis = dict(
    title = 'Shootings Incidents',
    type = 'linear'
  ),
  updatemenus = [dict(
        x = 0.1,
        y = 1.15,
        xref = 'paper',
        yref = 'paper',
        yanchor = 'top',
        active = 1,
        showactive = True,
        buttons = [
        dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'D1'],
            label = 'Day',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'D7'],
            label = 'Week',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M1'],
            label = 'Month',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M3'],
            label = 'Quater',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M6'],
            label = 'Half Year',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M12'],
            label = 'Year',
            method = 'restyle',
        )]
  )]
)

fig_dict = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

pio.show(fig_dict, validate=False)
```

Does anyone know how to get bins by week (as well as hypothetical bins by hour) to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do what I was trying to do. The answer was buried in the Plot.ly docs found here: https://plot.ly/python/reference/

Specifically under xbins.size, they refer to following the same scheme in axis.dtick. Here is the axis.dtick documentation that had the answer:

dtick
Parent: data[type=histogram].marker.colorbar
Type: number or categorical coordinate string

Sets the step in-between ticks on this axis. Use with `tick0`. Must be a positive number, or special strings available to "log" and "date" axes. If the axis `type` is "log", then ticks are set every 10^(n"dtick) where n is the tick number. For example, to set a tick mark at 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... set dtick to 1. To set tick marks at 1, 100, 10000, ... set dtick to 2. To set tick marks at 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, ... set dtick to log_10(5), or 0.69897000433. "log" has several special values; "L", where `f` is a positive number, gives ticks linearly spaced in value (but not position). For example `tick0` = 0.1, `dtick` = "L0.5" will put ticks at 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6 etc. To show powers of 10 plus small digits between, use "D1" (all digits) or "D2" (only 2 and 5). `tick0` is ignored for "D1" and "D2". **If the axis `type` is "date", then you must convert the time to milliseconds. For example, to set the interval between ticks to one day, set `dtick` to 86400000.0. "date" also has special values "M" gives ticks spaced by a number of months. `n` must be a positive integer. To set ticks on the 15th of every third month, set `tick0` to "2000-01-15" and `dtick` to "M3". To set ticks every 4 years, set `dtick` to "M48"**

As a result, the new snippet of code for the bin sizing is:

```
        buttons = [
        dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', ' 3600000.0'],
            label = 'Hour',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', '86400000.0'],
            label = 'Day',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', ' 604800000.0'],
            label = 'Week',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M1'],
            label = 'Month',
            method = 'restyle',
        )]
```

But with this in mind, I would have suspected that using "D1" wouldn't have worked either. If anyone who works at Plot.ly sees this, could you make a note to update the example to point out this specific nuance?